# how to write Topology Graph Edges geometry to polyline feature class

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, spatial-database

i have created topologygraph of a polygon feature . and iwant individual ids of polylines

i want to write Topology Graph Edges geometry to new polyline feature class

any samples OR documentation about this task?